# How to inject CDI dependency into JAX-RS ClientRequestFilter provider

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I have a @Provider that implements a ClientRequestFilter. The provider itself is not discovered at all. When I register it manually, then it is discovered.

```
ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(Somefilter.class);
```

This way however, CDI doesn't inject dependencies into Somefilter.

- AS: **WildFly 10**
- JAX-RS : **Resteasy** (built in WildFly)

The code of my **Somefilter** class looks like this.

```
@Provider
public class Somefilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

@Inject
private AccountService accountService;


@Override
public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(accountService);

}
```

}

The application also has a server part, configured with @Application annotation, using some classes implementing ContainerRequestFilter. These are discovered by Resteasy and even CDI injection works.

**So the question is**, how can I make client-api related providers inject CDI dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Provider` implementations are discovered automatically on the server side, but not on the client side.

Just try this:

```
@Inject
private Somefilter someFilter;

ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(someFilter);
```

Make sure to add a bean-defining annotation to `Somefilter` (e.g. `@Dependent`).

Comment: Is it possible to somehow have the filter instantiated per request ?

Comment: I suppose so, if the filter is `@RequestScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the correct package `javax.enterprise.context` for declaring the `@RequestScoped` scope for your service class:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class AccountService {

}
```

I was having this problem and found out I was erroneously using the Faces (JSF) package instead which was `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`.